# Time/Space Complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, space-complexity

Studying for an exam. I think the time complexity is O(n^2) and space is O(1). Please help, am I correct?

```
public static String lastSubstring(String s) {
    
    int start=0;
    int end = start+1;
    int len =0;
    
    while (end + len < s.length()) {

        if (s.charAt(start + len) == s.charAt(end + len)) {
            len++;
        } else if (s.charAt(start + len) > s.charAt(end + len)) {
            end += len + 1;
            len = 0;
        } else {
            start = end;
            end = start + 1;
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    return s.substring(start);
}
```

Comment: Space is only _O(1)_ if you don't count the return value. Since creating the return value is part of the method, the method's space complexity really is _O(n)_, where `n` is the length of the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(1), where n is the length of the input string.

Space complexity is O(1) because no extra space is used except for variables like 'start', 'end', 'len'. I have assumed here that you are not considering space occupied by returned string, If that is considered then space complexity will go to O(n) as at worst complete string of length n will be returned.

Time complexity is O(n) because the outer variable 'end' is only increasing from 0 to up n. The while loop breaks when the 'end' is greater than the input length n.

Time complexity would have been O(n^2), If for every 'end' iterating from 0 to n, you iterate another inner variable let say 'len' from 0 to n.
But in your case no of iterations is a function of 'end' + 'len', even if you have to start 'len' again from 0, no of iterations will only go up to n+n = 2n. That's why time complexity here is O(n).